# CORS with chrome 50.0.2661.86 in node

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cors

I m having an issue with, i think, last update of chrome in Mac. In previous versions of chrome it works fine, and actually with safari and firefox works fine too...

I  m developing a node.js app with CORS, i have implemented this way:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});
```

I m working with Ember, and the request is saving an object which generates a "normal" PATCH request :)

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/challenges/id
```

But, i guess since last update of chrome (50.0.2661.86), when i want to do a PATCH it returns me an error:

> Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in
>   preflight response

Do you have any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Chrome auto updates to new version and it has not happened again. Very strange issue, I don't know really what happened here...

Thanks to all responses :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the request? Is `PATCH` all uppercase? Does it work in Firefox? (Asking since it looks like your header setup is fine, though you may want to inspect that too to be sure.)

Comment: Hi Anne, thanks for your answer. Updated the question.

Comment: I can't edit mi previous comment but yes works in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Note that `ACA-Origin: *` and `ACA-Credentials: true` do not work together, but that cannot really be the problem I think if it works in Firefox and Safari. Might just be a Chrome bug.

Comment: That is, I'm assuming you don't include credentials in the request.

Comment: Yes, i m including credentials. But seems that error might not is related with...

Comment: Just test without ACA-Origin: * and same result received :(

Comment: What do you mean, without? Did you use an origin instead?

Comment: Also, is your server equipped to deal with preflight requests? See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol for details.

Comment: Yes, i used an origin and yes, my server is node based and i m using cors library (is working with Safari and Firefox). Thanks for your comments Anne :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it could resolve the problem, but try replacing `next()` with this:

```
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200);
    res.end();
}
else {
    next();
}
```

Maybe newer versions of chrome want to make the server handle the preflight response manually. Let me know what it responds.

Comment: Very strange issue.. +1 to the question because i'm interested in a solution too.

Comment: I can't test yet with PUT or DELETE but tested with POST and GET and both works.

Comment: Ok. If you test it with PUT and DELETE let me know.